# Pybind memory allocations vs python memory allocations

Tags: python, heap-memory, pybind11

Quite simple really, are objects created with pybind11 (cpython python3.9) in cpp allocated on the same heap as regular python objects, or do they have theor own seperate heap. here are two contradictory answers i got , one frm chatgpt and  another from bard:

chatgpt:

```
No, PyBind objects and regular Python objects are not allocated on the same heap.

PyBind is a library that allows you to create Python bindings for C++ code. It provides a bridge between C++ and Python, allowing you to use C++ classes and functions in Python code. When you use PyBind to expose C++ objects to Python, those objects are managed by the C++ memory management system and are allocated on the C++ heap.

On the other hand, regular Python objects, created and managed by the Python interpreter, are allocated on the Python heap. The Python heap is managed by the Python memory manager and uses its own allocation and deallocation mechanisms.

So, in summary, PyBind objects and regular Python objects reside in different memory spaces and are managed by different memory management systems.
```

bard:

```
Yes, Pybind objects and regular Python objects are allocated on the same heap. This is because Pybind is a C++ library that allows Python programmers to access C++ code. When a Pybind object is created, it is allocated on the heap just like any other Python object. The memory for the Pybind object is then managed by the Python garbage collector.

The only difference between Pybind objects and regular Python objects is that Pybind objects have a reference to the C++ object that they represent. This reference is used to keep the C++ object alive as long as the Pybind object is alive. When the Pybind object is garbage collected, the reference to the C++ object is also deleted, and the C++ object is then destroyed.
```

i tried looking a pybind [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes.html) and reviewing the source [code](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), but couldnt make sense of it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're on the same heap. The pybind11 code that allocates Python objects is [here](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/2fb3d7cbde264a0b3f921e802f287195387e8263/include/pybind11/detail/class.h#L358):

```
    PyObject *self = type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
```

`tp_alloc` in this case points to `PyType_GenericAlloc`, which is the default Python object construction function. It eventually calls `PyObject_Malloc` to allocate the actual memory.